# Visual Foxpro dBASE/dbf type solution for Linux

Tags: linux, lamp, foxpro, dbase

I am looking to take some propriety program which uses a dBASE backend and a FoxPro client to access it, and move it to a simple Linux solution.  Any suggestions for an open source Linux software which can easily import dbf files, and create a front end without much doing?

I am comfortable with Bash, Perl, Python, and html in that order, but I would prefer something that doesn't require much code on my end.

Comment: As you tagged your question in lamp, I'm supposing you can work with PHP... so http://www.grocerycrud.com/ can be what you are looking for.

Comment: Are you looking at building a desktop application or would browser based work for you? For web based perl I've been very pleased with the Dancer framework while python's django is pretty nice.

Comment: Web Based is what I am planning on.

Answer (score 2):

You could look at [Servoy](http://www.servoy.com). It:

- Runs on Linux
- Is based on an open-source Java stack (Tomcat/Terracotta/Wicket/Rhino/Hibernate) and is mostly open-source itself.
- Is database agnostic, and includes the ability to **connect to and work with DBF files directly**
- Coding is done in Javascript (Rhino) with the ability to inject client-side code directly when needed.
- Can target web and desktop from one codebase.
- Has a full drag-and-drop IDE which is basically modified Eclipse.